# Objective-C, sorting muti-dimensional arrays

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I've been having some trouble with sorting multi-dimensional arrays in Objective-C. I basically have an array of which every element is an array of the form:

```
(NSString, NSDate, NSString, NSString)
```

such that my top level array has the form:

```
(
(NSString, NSDate, NSString, NSString),
(NSString, NSDate, NSString, NSString),
(NSString, NSDate, NSString, NSString),
(NSString, NSDate, NSString, NSString),
...
)
```

I would like to be able to sort the elements of the top level array based on any of of their own elements. I wrote the following code which does this, but has proven to be far too inefficient for the large data sets I am dealing with.

```
-(NSMutableArray *) sortArrayByDate:(NSMutableArray *) unsortedArray {

    NSMutableArray * sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] init ];

    while ([unsortedArray count]>0) {
        int topIndex = 0;
        NSDate * topDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithString:@"1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0600"];
        for(int j=0;j<[unsortedArray count];j++) {
            NSDate * targetDate = [[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:1];
            if ([targetDate compare:topDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
                topDate = targetDate;
                topIndex = j;
            }            
        }
        [sortedArray addObject:[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:topIndex]];
        [unsortedArray removeObjectAtIndex:topIndex];        
    }    
    return sortedArray;
}
```

Can anyone please make a suggestion on how to accomplish this task using the more established methods of either sortUsingSelector or sortUsingDescriptor? If I was sorting a 1D array I think it would be something like:

```
[unsortedArray sortUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)]
```

but how do I tell it to sort using the nth value of the array I am passing it?

-Many thanks

-Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

in most cases, you would create an object:

```
@interface MONObject : NSObject
{
  NSString * a;
  NSDate * b;
  NSString * c;
  NSString * d;
}
...
```

then teach it to compare itself to others, then use those objects in the array. logical organization of data and implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't quite the answer I was looking for, but it was a quick and efficient solution.

Comment: you're welcome. an indirect solution to the problem is best in some cases. good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use blocks-based method [`sortUsingComparator:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-SW8) in `NSMutableArray` like this –

```
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^(id first, id second){
    id firstObject = [first objectAtIndex:1];
    id secondObject = [second objectAtIndex:1];

    return [firstObject compare:secondObject];
}]
```

You also have a parallel method [`sortedArrayUsingComparator:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator%3a) in `NSArray` which will spew out a sorted array.

**Sorting by varying indices**

```
typedef NSComparator (^ComparatorFactory)(id);

ComparatorFactory comparatorForIndex = ^NSComparator(id context) {
    NSInteger index = [(NSNumber*)context integerValue];
    NSComparator comparator = ^(id first, id second) {
        id firstObject = [first objectAtIndex:index];
        id secondObject = [second objectAtIndex:index];

        return [firstObject compare:secondObject];
    };

    return [[comparator copy] autorelease];
};

[myArray sortUsingComparator:comparatorForIndex([NSNumber numberWithInteger:1])];
```

Depending on the index passed, the array will sort based on objects at that index. This is pretty basic code but you can add to this.